# What is the meaning of “divest” in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is an example that the Longman Dictionary [provides](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/divest) to clarify usage of the word “divest”:

> Dad had long since divested himself of anything valuable.

Is this sentence talking about valuable attributes of the personality or just costly assets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This refers to assets.*

It’s *possible* in a certain context that this could follow your other interpretation, but this would be a metaphor and probably require a fairly pointed set-up, such as:

> She wondered if he’d retained any of the qualities she’d come to love before he started using. 
> Dad had long since divested himself of anything valuable.

Even in that case, it would be a double meaning; more or less a pun.

More likely (and, given the lack of context, the only real option) is that we could retain the meaning of the sentence rewriting it thus:

> At some time in the distant past, dad sold off his last asset of any worth.

---

**“Costly” is not necessary here. In general, “costly” is used to describe something that has been valuated too highly, not merely to indicate the presence of value or cash worth. It's basically synonymous with “expensive” but has wider metaphorical implications such as using “a costly foul” in sports to refer to a player committing a particularly poorly timed (or poorly located) infraction, incurring an impactful penalty.*